# Add multiple instances of a model with some shared fields at once

Tags: django

I'm trying to come up with a way of allowing a user to add multiple instances of a specific model at once in Django Admin, but with some fields being shared between them.

Example model:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    ref = models.ForeignKey(to="AnotherModel", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a page in Django Admin where the user would define the value of `ref` **field only once**, then add and populate as many `name` and `is_active` fields as he wants, press the Save button and the `ref` **field would get automatically re-used to create as many `Something` instances as the user created** with the `name` and `is_active` fields.

I know of Django's `StackedInLine` and `TabularInLine`, but I am not able to produce the above mentioned functionality with them, at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SomethingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Something
    extra = 1

class AnotherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAddmin):
    inlines = [SomethingInline]
```

this way you can create another model instance and add multiple inline items of **Something** model.